# What is expected number of trials until first success used for?

Tags: probability, statistics

For example having a probability p = 0.02 (2%) then the expected number of trials until success = 50 ( 1 / p).

What is expected number of trials until first success (1/p) used for? Any positive number of examples would be sufficient to answer the question.

Note: 1 / p is useful only if it can be used to reach further results that are useful.

For example the number Pi is useful because it can be used to calculate area of circles which is useful for knowing how much paint to buy for painting circles for example.

There is this common misconception that by performing 1 / p trials that guarantees 1 successful trial. And this misconception is an example as to why 1 / p can be used for detrimental purposes.

For any probability p > 0 and p < 1 it follows that no matter how many trials are performed it is not possible to say with 100% probability that 1 trial would be successful. As number of trials approaches infinity the chance of a successful trial approaches 100% but never reaches it.

For p = 0.02 after 35 trials the probability of 1 successful trial becomes higher than 50% and after 50 trials that probability is 63.58%. So why is 50 / 63.58% a special value in relationship with p? 35 trials would have made some sense since it would have been where it crossed the 50% mark, but I can't find any reasoning for 50 trials.

Comment: Perhaps for managing a company’s risk and optimizing the company’s expected welfare, or something along those lines. We use probabilities to deal with uncertainty, and to hedge our bets accordingly.

Comment: $\textrm{ ... of 1 successful trial becomes higher than 50% }$: This statement is too unspecific. What is your exact result? Also show the approach.

Comment: @callculus What is unclear about the question?

Comment: What is the exact result? That is my question.

Comment: @callculus This is my question: "What is expected number of trials until first success used for?" What is not clear to you about it?

Comment: Google for examples of the geometric distribution. But what you have calculated in the last paragraph has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @callculus I looked into that and could not find any examples for what it is useful for. If you do please provide an answer and I will gladly upvote and accept it.

Comment: $\texttt{What is not clear to you about it?}$ Nothing. But it is not clear why do you use the value 50% although it is **not exact**. It doesn´t make sense-mathematically

Comment: @callculus What do you mean by 50% not being exact?

Comment: quote:"higher than 50%"

Comment: I used 50% because when there are only 2 options covering all possibilities, going above 50% is what gives you the reasoning to pick one option over the other.

Comment: What is the exact value? Show what you have calculated.

Comment: The exact percentage value for 35 trials that crosses 50% is not really important for answering this question.

Comment: It is important. Because I want to find out what your (real) question is. Come on, show some effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85001/discussion-between-rzvan-flavius-panda-and-callculus).

Comment: There is no reason to switch to the chat.

Comment: @ziggurism why did you delete your use-case example comment? Was it not a good usage example?

Comment: because of your behavior

Comment: @ziggurism You have yet to provide any evidence that I said anything wrong, you are basically just insulting me.

Comment: @ziggurism Also, let's assume you asked a question I had an answer to. Would you say it is logical to not answer your question just because you upset me? I think that is a selfish choice as it shows lack of care for other people that might be interested in the answer.

Comment: stop lawyering at me

Answer (score 1):

This question is simultaneously vague, broad, interesting and unanswerable. I will try, and then possibly vote to close.

I think that you are asking a general question: what use is probability, since all it tells you are probabilities?

Well "what use is ..." is not really a mathematical question, unless you are asking for instances in which the theorem on the expected time to success in Bernoulli trials is used to prove other theorems. If that is what you mean, then edit the question to clarify.

In the real world we may use probability to help make decisions under uncertainty. If the probability of a hurricane in my town is $1/20$ each year I need to balance the cost a new hurricane resistant roof against the much larger cost (and inconvenience) of repairing hurricane damage. The fact that the roof will last more than $20$ years while the hurricane is likely to strike sooner is one factor that will influence my decision.

Examples like this, which I would not really consider a "use" of the theorem on Bernoulli trials, are probably the only possible answers to what I think you are asking.

Comment: "I think that you are asking a general question: what use is probability, since all it tells you are probabilities?" No, that is obviously not what I am asking. The question is in the title and reworded in the body also. So I do not know how you could possibly misunderstand it.

The question: What is expected number of trials until first success used for?

Comment: To answer the question you would have to give at least 1 example in which "expected number of trials until first success" is used for.

Comment: Also, how can you say the question is unanswerable if you do not even understand it? If the question really is unanswerable then why is "expected number of trials until first success" even a think in maths?

Comment: Since you think the question is unanswerable can you at least delete your non-answer - for obvious reasons? By giving others impression that the question has an answer, even though it does not, you are only hurting the community.

Comment: I don't think you're doing yourself any favors with the combative tone in these comments. If you don't see what use the expectation value of "number of trials to first success" is, since it does not guarantee anything because it is probabilistic, then do you see what use any expectation value is? Ethan gave a good faith attempt to address that, and you responded with hostility.

Comment: @ziggurism What hostility are you talking about? I am just asking him to delete his "answer" since even he admits that it is not an answer. My goal is for questions to have actual answers.

Comment: well you'll be happy to know i deleted my answer at least

Comment: @ziggurism Why would that make me happy I was hoping you actually had a good usage example for "expected number of trials until first success".

Comment: @ziggurism since you are not going to point to what "hostility" I shown, I will just act like you are making stuff up